# Laravel: redirect with custom error but without error message

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Consider the manual authentication. If the **order ID** has not been found in database, we redirect user to page with input fields and with error `'wrongOrderId'`:

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $inputted_orderId = $request->input('order_id');       
    $orderIdInDB = DB::table(self::SITE_IN_DEVELOPMENT_TABLE_NAME)
            ->where(self::ORDER_ID_FIELD_NAME, $inputted_orderId)->first();

   if (is_null($orderIdInDB)) {
       return Redirect::route('loginToSitesInDevelopmentZonePage')->withErrors('wrongOrderId');
   }               
}
```

In this example, we **don't** need to pass the error **message**: the message box is already exists in View; all we need is to display this message box when user has been redirected with error `'wrongOrderId'`:

```
@if (!empty($errors->first('wrongOrderId'))) 
    <div class="signInForm-errorMessagebox" id="invalidID-errorMessage">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
@endif
```

All above code is working without laravel/php errors; I get into `is_null($orderIdInDB)` if-block when input wrong order number, however the  error message box don't appears. I tried a lot of ways, and `(!empty($errors->first('wrongOrderId')))` is just last one. What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try printing `{{$errors->first()}}`?

`first(string)`, works as a key value pair, it invokes its first key VALUE

try this,

```
 @if($errors->any())
    <div class="signInForm-errorMessagebox" id="invalidID-errorMessage">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I successfully printed `$errors->first()`. ` @if($errors->any())` also works. How to check the specific error, I learned in  user2486's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific error from validator error, use the `get()` method.

`$errors->get('wrongOrderId');` get all the `wrongOrderId` errors.

`$errors->first('wrongOrderId');` get first error of `wrongOrderId` errors

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Hmm... When I try `$errors->first('wrongOrderId');`, the error don't appears yet. Is `->withErrors('wrongOrderId');` OK with your solution? Also, when I tried `$errors->get('wrongOrderId');`, I got the strange exception: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. `{{$errors->first()}}` is working: `wrongOrderId` is displaying.

Comment: Use this code in your blade php, not controller. add in the `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}`

Answer (score 0):

I explored that `$errors->first('wrongOrderId')` has non-displayable but non-null value. So `@if ( $errors->first('wrongOrderId')  !== null )` will work.

Something more elegantly like `@if ($errors->first('wrongOrderId'))`? Unfortunately just one this check is not enough: even if we define

```
return Redirect::route('loginToSitesInDevelopmentZonePage')->withErrors(['wrongOrderId' => true]);
```

php will convert `true` to 1. So, `@if ( $errors->first('wrongOrderId')  == true )` will working, but `@if ($errors->first('wrongOrderId'))` will not.

However, we can to cast `$errors->first('wrongOrderId')` to `bool`, so the most elegant solution will be

`@if ((bool) $errors->first('wrongOrderId'))`